# YouTube Iframe-API: getting the iframe-id inside 'onStateChange' function

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I am using the YouTube JavaScript API to control the YouTube Players on my page. The Goal is to stop all currently playing Videos, when i start a new one.

*Already going through the struggle of different kinds of YouTube Embed options, like single videos, playlist etc. i came to a question, which would make my life much more easier.*

Initializing the players like this:

```
// Array to store YTplayers
var YTplayers = [];

// Select all YouTube iframes
var YTembeds = $('iframe[src*="youtube.com"], iframe[src*="youtube-nocookie.com"]'); 

YTEmbeds.each(function(i) {
    iframe = $(this);

    // Generate and add the unique identifier for the current iframe
    var iframe_id = "iframe-youtube-" + i;
    iframe .attr("id", iframe_id);

    // Check if src already has a "?" and add "?" or "&" accordingly
    // then add the necessary "enablejsapi=1" option and update the src. 
    var url = iframe .attr("src");
    url += url.indexOf("?") == -1 ? "?" : "&";
    iframe.attr("src", url + "enablejsapi=1");

    // Create YouTube Player Object with custom eventListener
    player = new YT.Player( iframe_id, {
                  events: {
                    'onStateChange': onYouTubePlayerStateChange
                  }
                });

    // Store the new player element and the iframe_id together
    YTplayers.push({
        "id" : iframe_id,
        "player" : player
    });
});
```

Now inside the function **"onYouTubePlayerStateChange"**, there i have access to the "event"-object, but there is only information about the embedded youTube-Player and nothing ... i can find ... about the surrounding iframe-object.

So the question is: How can i get access to the iframe-id, which got used to initialize the YT-Player, INSIDE the function "onYouTubePlayerStateChange"?

PS: For now i have used the video_id, or playlist_id, which are stored in the event-object to identify the iframe. But then when i have two players with the same YT-video_id, although this case is unlikely, they will both keep running.

Thanks for any effort to help me with this problem.

Kindly,

Max K

Answer (score 8):

So finally i found a pretty simple solution, to pass an argument to the eventListener function by wrapping it in with another function, and passing the default "event" object PLUS the customly defined iframe_id, like so:

```
player = new YT.Player( iframe_id, {
              events: {
                'onStateChange': function(event){
                  onYouTubePlayerStateChange(event, iframe_id);
                }
              }
            });
```

Now, in the "onYouTubePlayerStateChange" function you have access to both the youtube-event-object with the current state of the player and the iframe_id that defines which player it actually is.

Cheers!

Comment: Five years later, this answer is relevant! Been struggling with the same thing. The YT object property changed from `a` to `f` recently, so the code we have to control multiple YouTube videos was starting to break. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Another way to get id of iframe:

```
jQuery(event.target.getIframe()).attr('id')
```

Answer (score 3):

as [@Dmitro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1202013/dmitro) mentioned you can use `getIframe()` method, solution without jQuery:

```
event.target.getIframe().id
```